# Calling Firebase Functions v2 from Angular using Angular Fire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

I am having small issue, after I migrated my Firebase Cloud Function (onCall) to v2 they suggest that it should be called via URL using `httpsCallableFromURL` from 'firebase/functions'. However, in our Angular project, we use https://github.com/angular/angularfire for calling the Cloud Functions. In `AngularFireFunctions` there is only method `httpsCallable(name: string, options?: HttpsCallableOptions)` which does not allow for calling function using URL.
Any idea how to call v2 function from AngularFire by url?

Comment: As a workaround firebase SDK can be used directly
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/callable#call_the_function

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `httpsCallableFromURL` and still use `@angular/fire`, you could use their new modular SDK (which got introduced [with version 7](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md#new-modular-sdk)).

Note, that this new SDK requires a slightly different setup of the app module, different injectable classes and functions, which have to be imported directly. See details in [the sample of the AngularFire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/samples/modular/src/app).

With this setup, you can import the `httpsCallableFromURL` function to your service, component and use it (this basically uses the firebase SDK under the hood directly - see [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/functions/firebase.ts)).